# Best implementation of a vector of vectors in C++

Tags: c++

I have a vector of vectors and I'd like to know if, with C++, there is a better structure to define V of Vs in terms of time/space complexity.

For example, V of Vs is better than a Map of vectors? equivalent?

Thanks in advance.
NL

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  This generally determines what you should use.

Comment: If you want a 2d array then using a 1D vector and the index calculation `(x + y * width)` is usually faster. You can wrap this in a class.

Comment: You might want to add *what* you want to do with that 2d-matrix. Also: Are all the "inner" vectors the same size or are they of varying sizes? If they are the same size, follow @NeilKirk's advice and use row-major or column-major on a simple vector.

Comment: I think that the "-3" is a bit harsh, I often see questions here about nesting STL classes, and this clearly deserves discussion (yes, the question is not sufficiently precise, but I think it deserves to be answered)

Answer (score 3):

In general, if you got a large number of elements, it is not a good idea to nest two STL classes, because STL containers have a certain overhead as compared to just the stored element sizes. If you nest two STL containers, then this overhead gets multiplied by the number of elements of the "outer" container.

If you need a 2D array with rows that have different lengths, then you can use the "compressed row storage" format [1], it is widely used in numerical algorithms, to represent sparse matrices.

References:
[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_row_Storage_.28CRS_or_CSR.29

Comment: +1 agree totally.  The vector of vectors is nuts and I'm quite surprised there's no multidimensional vector object in the standard library (though I think there's one in boost).

Comment: Did you mean to link the article in German rather than this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix

Comment: Thank you for noticing (fixed)